# Apex Data Loader "failed to create batch"

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I'm trying to use Apex Data Loader to load 4 20mb PowerPoints into SFDC. I was able to load smaller files using the same CSV file (just changing the file names). Once I try to load these  larger files, I get "failed to create batch," and no other details. What causes this and how can I fix it?

Comment: I've got same problem, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I believe I was able to fix it in the Data Loader settings by setting Batch Size to 1. I can't remember though. Try that, and if it doesn't work, I'll try to recreate the issue.

Comment: Yes @Kristin, this did it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In our cases, reducing batch size is key. I imagine this is related to max overall size the bulk upload API can handle at any given time. Larger individual attachments to upload will require smaller batch sizes.